En mi Visual Studio Code No tabula mi codigo cuando salta de linea
Mi codigo en HTML en este caso específico, cuando salta de línea no respeta la tabulación, necesiito saber en que parte de los ajustes de visual studio code puedo corregir esta caracteristica. Tuve que desinstalar y reinstalar y por esa razón tengo esa característica que me incomoda trabajar cuando debo dividir la pantalla.

Se llama Word wrap. Puedes encontrar la configuración en el menú View.

Imagen tomada de esta respuesta.

No, no es el tipico problema de word wrap, porque no es que sigue de largo. Se adapta al tamaño de la pantalla pero cuando debe saltar de línea porque es largo, la siguiente línea no viene tabulada, empieza desde el borde izquierdo.

settings.json: editor.wrappingIndent
Controla la sangría de las líneas ajustadas.

deepIndent: A las líneas ajustadas se les aplica una sangría de +2 respecto al elemento primario.
indent: A las líneas ajustadas se les aplica una sangría de +1 respecto al elemento primario.
same: A las líneas ajustadas se les aplica la misma sangría que al elemento primario.
none: No hay sangría. Las líneas ajustadas comienzan en la columna 1.

